# ¿Cómo puedo comenzar a aprender/estudiar este nuevo mundo?

Tags: lógica

quiero y estoy comenzando con este mundo de la programacion, les agradeceria que me aconsejen a como empezar. Gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so]: haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Tu pregunta está basada en opiniones, por lo tanto es casi seguro que terminará [cerrada](/help/closed-questions). Cuando tengas suficiente [reputación](/help/privileges) podrás acceder al chat del sitio, en donde este tipo de preguntas son mejor bienvenidas. Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](/help/on-topic).